# Video autoplay doesn't work without hard refresh

Tags: html, html5-video

I have a video background. It uses autoplay. Here it is:

```
<video muted loop autoPlay >
    <source src="assets/videos/background.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

This works ONLY if the page is: 
 1. Hard refreshed (normal load does not work)
 2. Navigated to (If I am on another page and then navigate to the home page)

If you simply navigate to the link, it doesn't work. Link: https://jackseabolt.github.io/trasher/ (please don't mess with the site)

Any thoughts about what's going on here?

Comment: In which browsers (especially versions) this happens?

Comment: Right now I'm in Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139

Comment: i suggest this: https://github.com/videojs/video.js

Comment: @JSeabolt try with version 65 if you can, it might be because latest implementations of autoplay rules of Chrome 66 even if yours is muted it should not be. Try using "controls" to see if anything is changed.

Comment: controls did not do anything. I've had this issue in React. Muting the video fixed this issue. Not in Angular though

Comment: Seems to be working just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: If this is HTML, try using autoplay with a lowercase p

Comment: Yeah I've tried "autoplay", "autoPlay", "autoplay="autoplay"" None of them seem to do the trick

Comment: It may work in older browsers. In my Chrome and Safari it does not. So there's clearly something going on. Can't have it going out with it only working sometimes. Hmmm

Comment: You could try playing it with Javascript instead of the `autoplay` tag. I am able to recreate the issue in Chrome and in Firefox there's a different issue where the video is very laggy. Maybe re-encoding the video would help?

Comment: Yeah I'm considering that. Looks like other people have had a similar issue. Where would you put the code for that? In the component?

Answer (score 22):

You didn't say that using an Angular in your project. That's simple now:

```
<video [muted]="true" autoplay playsinline loop>
    <source src="your_video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Just change `muted` attribute to `[muted]="true"`.

Comment: I'm having this exact issue but, none of the solutions mentioned here work for me......I'm using WordPress and the code looks exactly the same

Answer (score 6):

Adding the muted attribute to the video works. This is a browser feature to make sure noisy videos don't autoplay.

Comment: I was thinking that it is a bug but when read your answer realized that it is a feature. Thanks

Comment: I thought not having an audio track would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

In my case same issue happened your solution worked for me but with slight change instead of `muted` being in the `[]` replaced it to:

```
<video muted="true" autoplay playsinline loop>
    <source src="your_video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And then it worked for me  using it in an angular webpage.

Comment: I wonder to know in what case `muted` hasn't worked with `[]`?

Comment: In my case, it's the opposite. bruh I'm confused

Answer (score 0):

Google prevents force manipulations in Chrome to start a video on a refresh or by typing direct URL.
**NONE** of these methods worked:

```
setTimeout(this.videoStarts,300); // works only time to time, so isn't reliable
```

**Not** with jQuery, **nor** with React refs:

```
this.video.current.play();
$('.video').get(0).play(); // simply won't work
```

**To solve it** you can add interactions: 
1. Create a modal window which will ask a user to agree on playing a content. 

**OR**
2. Add an onclick event on a needed tag which will fire `play()`.

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem.

`video.play()` returns promise.

This code might help you.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {

  var promise = document.querySelector('video').play();

  if (promise !== undefined) {
      promise.catch(error => {
          console.log ("Auto-play failed")
          // Auto-play was failed
      }).then(() => {
          console.log ("Auto-play started")
          // Auto-play started
      });
  }
});
```

or `CoffeeScript`

```
document.addEventListener 'DOMContentLoaded', (e) ->
  promise = document.querySelector('video').play()
  if promise != undefined
    promise.catch((error) ->
      console.log 'Auto-play failed'
    ).then ->
      console.log 'Auto-play started'
```

Comment: explain in a nutshell what your code snippet is doing, and why that would/could solve the problem.