# Cannot play MP4 video again after refreshing webpage in Angular

Tags: angular, mp4

I can display the video on the first time but then I Cannot play MP4 video again after refreshing webpage.

I have to save HTML to be able to display the video again on webpage.

```
**
<header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
    <source src="../../assets/hki.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</header>
**
```

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Change `muted` into `[muted]="true"` as this example :

```
<header>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" [muted]="true" loop="loop">
    <source src="../../assets/hki.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</header>
```

Attribution for @hifull in (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56890204/14945696)