# HTML: Video only plays after hard referesh

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

Currently, I'm using WordPress to make my graphic design portfolio. In it, I have a section of videos, which play when the user hovers on them. Today I noticed

**Bug: The video Only played When the page is hard refreshed**

I followed the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279454/video-autoplay-doesnt-work-without-hard-refresh?answertab=votes#tab-top) but none of the mentioned answer work for me work for me

```css
.img-filter img, .img-filter video {
        margin:0 auto;
        opacity:0.5;
        filter: grayscale(1);
        transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

.img-filter:hover img, .img-filter:hover video {
        opacity:1;
        filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<figure class="wp-block-video img-filter">
    <video height="320px" muted="true" class="clip" playinline loop>
        <source src="https://vedsarkar.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Hummingbird_V2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</figure>

<script>
    const clip = document.querySelectorAll('.clip');
    for (let i = 0; i < clip.length; i++) {
        clip[i].addEventListener('mouseenter',
            function(e){
                clip[i].currentTime = 0
                clip[i].play()
            })
        clip[i].addEventListener('mouseout',
            function(e){
                clip[i].pause()
            })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The code run here perfectly....but does not work in my domain

Comment: Did you find a solution?